# Automate backup of Pervasive tables

Tags: pervasive

On one of my server, I have a Pervasive V8 installed. I need to get the data from some tables.

It's possible manually, just Click Right on table, then Export Data.

But, there is a way to automate these Exports ? Sorry, but documentation about Pervasive is very poor.

Answer (score 0):

Ther is no to automate the export through the Pervasive tools.  If you want to just export the tables to CSV (what Export Data does), you can use any number of ODBC enabled tools to export to CSV.  Most of them can be automated through task scheduler.